# Matlab, save output in array , loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, output, store

I want to create an array that can store the outputs each time that doing a loop. I think the problem is because in a every new iteration the numbers starts counting from the beginning so it stores only the last iteration! In each iteration the output is an `array(7x3)` so in total I have to have `(28,3)`.But I tried a lot and i AM GETTING AN `ARRAY (28,3)` all with zeros except  the last 7 rows. 
Thank you very much

You can see the code below:

```
 for t=1:ncell % in my case I have 4 cells
    ti=sort(T,2)              
    tt= sort(Cell{t}.ExBot,2)
    tq= sort(Cell{t}.ExTop,2)
    te= sort(Cell{t}.ExBT,2)
    %k=0
    z=0
    cc=[]
    %%%%% for exbottom
    I=ones(size(ti,1),1);
    for j=1:size(tt,1)
        for i=1:size(ti,1)
            if tt(j,:)==ti(i,:)
                k=k+1 ;
                %c(k,:)=[ti(j,:), ti(j+1,:)]
                I(i)=0;

                cc(k,:)=Y(i,:);
                cc(size(tt,1)+1,:)=cc(1,:)




            else
            end

        end


    end

end
```

Comment: What is the value of `k` at the end of the loop?

Comment: In case you like to get a verifiable answer, please post missing variables like `T` and `Cell`. Make sure the code you are posting is executable.

Comment: Debug the code, adding a breakpoint at the "if .."

Comment: the k value is just a value to write the first row of output first...and its change by each time! Also the T is triangulation  of my mesh. So the cc are the position around each cell which is an array (7x3).. In my case I have four cells so I have i want a general array that gonna contains all the position around of each cell that means an array (28,3).. There is no variable cell but ncell which is equal to 4( that means 4 cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although more info would help as mentioned in the comments, from the information you've given, the problem is most likely in setting cc to empty when you start processing each cell.

```
cc=[];
```

On exiting the outermost loop you will only have results for the last iteration.

On a related note you may want to use `isequal` or `all` for the comparison of vectors i.e. `if isequal(tt(j,:),ti(i,:))`